# Duplicate class I'm already using ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio in my code: 5.1.0-LTS for audio conversion video_editor: ^2.1.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ffmpeg

I'm already using in my code: ffmpeg_kit_flutter_audio-5.1.0-LTS
for audio conversion, when you put the
video_editor: ^2.1.0
general the error, is there any way to solve it?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Abi found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.AbiDetect found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.AbstractSession found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.AsyncFFmpegExecuteTask found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.AsyncFFprobeExecuteTask found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.AsyncGetMediaInformationTask found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.CameraSupport found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Chapter found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKit found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig$1 found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig$2 found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKitConfig$SAFProtocolUrl found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegSession found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFprobeKit found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFprobeSession found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFprobeSessionCompleteCallback found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Level found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Log found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.LogCallback found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.LogRedirectionStrategy found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.MediaInformation found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.MediaInformationJsonParser found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.MediaInformationSession found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.MediaInformationSessionCompleteCallback found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.NativeLoader found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Packages found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.ReturnCode found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Session found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.SessionState found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Signal found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Statistics found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.StatisticsCallback found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)
> Duplicate class com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.StreamInformation found in modules jetified-ffmpeg-kit-audio-5.1.LTS-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS) and jetified-ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl-5.1-runtime (com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the exception message, The issue is caused by duplicate classes found in modules "ffmpeg-kit-audio:5.1.LTS" and "ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:5.1". So there are basically two references for each class. I remember that I faced this issue a while ago and I tried different solutions from enabling Androidx(android.useAndroidX=true) and Jetifier (android.enableJetifier=true) to "exclude"ing, "force"ing, and "configure"ing the dependencies in the  build.gradle but nothing worked properly.

Also, I was using [the "full" license](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit) and I experienced this issue with packages depending on other licenses such as min, min-gpl, https-gpl. So in order to override the ffmpeg dependency of the package which was causing the issue,  I downloaded the source file from its repository. Then I [created a custom package](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-dart-packages-for-flutter/) inside my main folder using "Flutter create --template=package name_of_the_package". I moved all the source files from the downloaded package to the new package folder. While adding the dependencies from the downloaded pubspec.yaml file to the new pubspec.yaml, I simply replaced the original dependency "ffmpeg_kit_flutter_https: 5.1.0" by the new "ffmpeg_kit_flutter_full: 5.1.0-LTS" dependency inside the new pubspect.yaml. Then I was able to start the app and it was working as expected.

One of the dependencies(video_editor)is using min-gpl license. You need to provide these codec libraries(vid.stab,x264, x265,xvidcore) as long as you are using that dependency. You can create a custom package and set your ffmpeg license to "full-gpl" which includes the audio and min-gpl libraries but pay attention to the licensing of gpl modules.